# Setting default value of formic field to 0 as to show the field filled with innitial value of 0 other than being empty

Tags: reactjs, formik

I want to input the default value of the field to 0, I'm using formik to develop the form. I have tried setting initial value to 0 in input props but it's not working.

Comment: Do you have an example code of what you already made?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this on the `value` prop using a `one-line if statement` , like as follow:

```
<input
   type="type"
   name="name"
   value={values.value ? values.value : 0}
/>
```

This will use `0` when the variable you're using i'ts null, empty, etc

Answer (score -1):

You can try "placeholder" in the field.

```
<Field name="Amount" type="text" placeholder="0" />
```